# What are some incapabilities that the early spectroscopy have when compared to the more modern method?

Tags: spectroscopy

What are some incapabilities that the earlier spectroscopy (Visible, Ultraviolet and Infra-red) have when compared to the more modern method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the things that come to mind are:

- **Resolution**  Modern equipment has much higher resolution than older equipment.  Optical component surface smoothness and uniformity, optical component alignment and electrical component stability all permit the user to see more detail and fine structure in the spectrum, which assists in analysis
- **More stable light sources**  Again resulting in more detailed and more reproducible spectra
- **Improved monochromaticity of the light sources**  Further improving spectral resolution
- **Improved sample cells**  Polished glass surfaces provide for better signal to noise making it easier to discern the signal
- **Signal processing software**  Such as Fourier Transform methods which increase the signal to noise ratio making it easier to discern the true peaks in a spectrum
- **Other computer and software enhancements**  That can be applied to sample handling and spectrum processing.  They dramatically reduce the time it takes to record and process a spectrum